# invalid read size of 1 valgrind

Tags: c++, valgrind

I've been scratching my hair out but can't seem to find what is wrong with the following code. Here is the small snippet of valgrind output that it generates

> Invalid read of size 1 at 0x4c22d82: strlen (mc_replace_strmem.c:242)
>   by 0x5E65CA: Application::readConfigurationFile() (char_traits.h:262)
>   by 0x5694BD: main Address 0xafc9660 is 24 bytes inside a block of size
>   39 free'd at 0x4C20E0D: operator delete(void*)
>   (vg_replace_malloc.c:342) by 0x635618:
>   Configurator::getParameterValue(char const*, char**) by 0x5E65B2:
>   Application:readConfigurationFile() (Application.cpp:77) by 0x5694BD:
>   main

```
bool Configurator::getParameterValue(const char *p_pParameterName, char** p_pParameterValue)
{
    bool blReturnValue = false;

    QDomElement element;
    QDomNode node;
    QDomNodeList list;

    list = doc.elementsByTagName(p_pParameterName);
    if (!list.isEmpty())  
    {
        node = list.item(0);
        element = node.toElement();
        QString qs = element.text().toUtf8();
        *p_pParameterValue = (char *)(qs.toStdString().c_str());
        blReturnValue = true;
    }
    else
    {
        char sMessage[200];
        sprintf(sMessage, "<Configurator::getParameterValue> Error! Parameter %s could not be found\n", p_pParameterName);
        m_outputFunction(sMessage);
    }

    return blReturnValue;
}

bool Configurator::parseFile()
{
    bool blReturnValue = false;

    QString errorStr;
    int errorLine;
    int errorColumn;

    if (!doc.setContent((QIODevice*)(&file), true, &errorStr, &errorLine, &errorColumn))
    {
        char aTemp[512];
        sprintf(aTemp, "<Configurator::parseFile> error! can not read the file row: %d, column: %d:\n",errorLine, errorColumn);
        m_outputFunction(aTemp);
    }
    else
    {
        closeFile();
        blReturnValue = true;
    }

    return blReturnValue;
}

bool Application::readConfigurationFile()
{
    bool blReturnValue = false;

    m_outputFunction("<Application::readConfigurationFile> Reading configuration..\n");

    if(m_configurator.parseFile())
    {
        blReturnValue = true;

        m_configurator.writeParameters();

        char *pTemp = 0;


        if(!m_configurator.getParameterValue("center_no", m_bCenterNo)) 
            m_bCenterNo = 1;
        if(m_configurator.getParameterValue("highway_header", &pTemp))
            m_strHighwayHeader.assign(pTemp);
        else
            m_strHighwayHeader.assign("... HIGHWAY"); // Default value
    }
    return blReturnValue;
}
```

Can somebody please tell me why I see invalid reads, I don't even use malloc/calloc in this code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in effect returning a pointer to a local variable. In `getParameterValue` the variable `qs` is local inside a block, and you assign that strings pointer to `p_pParameterValue`. When `getParameterValue` the stack space formerly occupied by `qs` is now reclaimed and the pointer pTemp now points to unused memory. This is *undefined behavior*, and can cause lots of bad stuff to happen.

Comment: thanks for the response, so instead of doing that I should have used strncpy, is that right?

Comment: @erinc No, then you have to allocate and free memory. My suggestion is that you either use a reference to a `QString` or `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

```
*p_pParameterValue = (char *)(qs.toStdString().c_str());
```

Why you did so? QString is local variable and `toStdString` return new `std::string`

```
std::string QString::toStdString () const
```

So, returned std::string will be deleted. c_str() returns pointer to const char*. Quote from n3337 draft:

```
const charT* c_str() const noexcept;
const charT* data() const noexcept;
```

> 1 Returns: A pointer p such that p + i == `&operator[](i)` for
>   each i in `[0,size()]`. 2 Complexity: constant time. 3 Requires: The
>   program shall not alter any of the values stored in the character
>   array.

```
if(m_configurator.getParameterValue("highway_header", &pTemp))
                m_strHighwayHeader.assign(pTemp);
```

Wrong. Since value in pTemp was deleted, when temporary object `qs.toStdString()` was deleted.

Answer (score 1):

The temporary string object returned from `qs.toStdString()` allocates memory for the string, which is freed when the temporary is destroyed (after evaluation of the full expression). If you are compiling with optimization, it is likely that the `std::string` d'tor is inlined into your function, so it doesn't show up in your call stack.

When you want to continue using the string data after the function is done, you need to make it persist. The (in my opinion) sanest way is to return a `std::string` object rather than a `char *`, so the last parameter could be a `std::string **` (which is filled by `new std::string(qs.toStdString())`), or a `std::string &` which is assigned to.

If you have the Boost libraries, you can also use `boost::optional<std::string>` as the return type, which provides a "string with a valid flag" data type.